# How to embed multipart/mixed in a multipart/form-data?

Tags: rest, jax-rs, cxf, multipart

In CXF JAX-RS how can we produce this request from java client side:

Note the multipart/mixed embedded in the multipart/form-data.

```
--bqJky99mlBWa-ZuqjC53mG6EzbmlxB 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="owner" 
Content-Type: text/plain 

Larry 
--bqJky99mlBWa-ZuqjC53mG6EzbmlxB 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files" 
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=_Part_4_701508.1145579811786 

--_Part_4_701508.1145579811786 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="book1" 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=US-ASCII 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 

{"Book":{"name":"CXF in Action - 1","id":123}} 
--_Part_4_701508.1145579811786 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="book2" 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=US-ASCII 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 

{"Book":{"name":"CXF in Action - 2%","id":124}} 
--_Part_4_701508.1145579811786-- 
--bqJky99mlBWa-ZuqjC53mG6EzbmlxB--
```

[This is from the CXF doc here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-multiparts.html):

> Finally, multipart/form-data requests with multiple files (file uploads) can 
>   be supported too. For example, this request can be handled by a method with 
>   the signature like:
>
> ```
> @POST 
> @Path("/books/filesform") 
> @Produces("text/xml") 
> @Consumes("multipart/form-data") 
> public Response addBookFilesForm(@Multipart("owner") String name, 
>                                  @Multipart("files") List<Book> books) {}
> ```

But how to generate that request from the java client side?

Of course, you can always post a List of Attachment s. 
But how to put the multipart/mixed in one of the attachments?

I tried putting a list of attachments (representing the multipart/mixed) in one of the attachments, but didt't work.

Comment: I don't use CXF, but just a guess, how about `MultipartBody`

Comment: Hi and thanks. I tried that too but the generated request is not at all the expected one.

Answer (score 0):

See the ["Writing attachments" section](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-multiparts.html#JAX-RSMultiparts-Writingattachments) in the documentaion.

Cited example:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://books");
client.type("multipart/mixed").accept("multipart/mixed");
List<Attachment> atts = new LinkedList<Attachment>();
atts.add(new Attachment("root", "application/json", new JSONBook()));
atts.add(new Attachment("image", "application/octet-stream", getImageInputStream()));
List<Attachment> atts = client.postAndGetCollection(atts, Attachment.class);
```